# How to implement dependency injection in asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2

I wanted to use this nuget package in my .net web api project:
https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/tree/885a98151be242516ec57cd94da1747b72588788

The idea was to consume that nuget package from a  .net web api in 4.6.1 however this package targets netstandard 2. So I couldnt install the nuget package.

At the end, I downloaded the source code and created a new class library in .net 4.6.1 and it compiles perfect.

Then I added a reference from .net web api to this library.

However I am having issues with the serviceCollection, as this is not there. 
How do I use it serviceCollection?

```
// [Authorize]
    public class TenantController : ApiController
    {
        private  CosmosStoreSettings cosmosSettings;

        public TenantController()
        {

            cosmosSettings = new CosmosStoreSettings(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"].ToString(), 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"].ToString(), 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"].ToString());

            serviceCollection.AddCosmosStore<Book>(cosmosSettings);

        }
```

> The name 'serviceCollection' does not exist in the current context

I know exactly what it means, but I am not sure how to implement DI on this project

Comment: What DI container are you using?

Comment: none, no experience with DI, so I can use any you tell me and its easy to implement

Comment: Reference [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Comment: I already read that page before posting the question, but its not clear to me how to use that in my context

Comment: please tell me how in a detailed answer

Comment: lol -4 what a shame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library you are using uses the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` NuGet package, which contains the Dependency Injection framework that ASP.NET Core uses. While it is not dependent on ASP.NET Core (not even on .NET Core), given that you are using ASP.NET Web API 2, I would suggest you to keep it simple and just create a factory around `ComosStore<T>`:

```
public static class CosmosStoreFactory 
{
    private static CosmosStoreSettings _settings = new CosmosStoreSettings("<<databaseName>>", "<<cosmosUri>>", "<<authkey>>");

    public static ICosmosStore<T> CreateForEntity<T>() where T: class
    {
         return new CosmosStore<T>(_settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, but I get this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0452 The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'ICosmosStore<TEntity>' TenantManagementWebApi C:\Users\levm3\source\repos\TenantManagementWebApi\Factories\CosmosStoreFactory.cs 13 Active

Comment: @LuisValencia See the update, the problem was the generic constraint on the method

Comment: trying to know how to use the factory in my controller

Comment: @LuisValencia That would be just `var bookStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Book>()`

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented **Dependency injection** with **WebAPI2**, [Get the GITHUB code here!](https://github.com/BikramChhetri/CMS.git)
Just download the application and go through the code. It is a very simple CRUD application. Please go through the README.md file.

There are several dependency injection containers available:
I have used **Unity**.

Steps to add **Unity.**
1.Add the library **Unity.AspNet.WebAp** to your application.
2.UnityConfig.cs file will be added to your APP_START folder.

then follow the code I have done in the sample application.